# Split sitemaps writes whole query to one file in PHP

Tags: php, sitemap

I have written this sitemap creation function where it writes to multiple pages splitting 1000 links.

```
<?php
//write sitemap file
function BuildSitemap($filename,$header,$footer,$body,$filetype,&$i){
    global $config;
    $ffile = $config['basedir'].'/'.$filename.$i.$ext;
    $fp = @fopen($ffile, "wa+");

        $filecontent = $header.'\n'.$body.'\n'.$footer;
        fwrite($fp, $filecontent);
        fclose($fp);
    $i++;
}

function Sitemap_posts(){
    global $config,$con;
    $k = '';
    $header = '';
    $footer = '';
    $body = '';
    $ensm = $config['en_sm'];//enable
    $burl = $config['burl'];

    if($ensm == "1"){
        $frequency  = 'weekly';
        $priority           = '0.8000';


        //MAKE DB QUERIES
        $sql = $con->Execute("SELECT `perma`, `subtime`
            FROM `posts` 
            WHERE `pstatus` = '1'
            ORDER BY `id` DESC");

        $header .= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'."\n"; 
        $header .= '<urlset
            xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">';
        $footer .= '</urlset>';

        $count = $sql->RecordCount();
        $page =  ceil($count/1000);
        $maxlink = 1000;
        for($i=0;$i < $page;$i++){
            //if($i < $maxlink){
                $stfrom = ($i) * $maxlink;
            //} else {
                //$stfrom = 0;
            //}                 

            $Query = "SELECT `perma`, `subtime`
                FROM `posts` 
                WHERE `pstatus` = '1'
                ORDER BY `id` DESC
                LIMIT ".$stfrom.", ".$maxlink;
                //echo $Query."<br>";
            $sub = $con->Execute($Query);
            $scount = $sub->RecordCount();
            $results = $sub->getrows();
            if($scount > 0){
                //while ($row = $sub->FetchRow()){
                for($j=0;$j<count($results);$j++){
                $post_link = $MasterUrl.'/'.$results[$j]['perma'].'/';
                    $body .= '<url>
                        <loc>'.$post_link.'</loc>
                        <lastmod>'.datetimeToutc($results[$j]['subtime']).'</lastmod> 
                        <changefreq>'.$frequency.'</changefreq> 
                        <priority>'.$priority.'</priority>  
                    </url>';
                }
                $filename = "postsitemap";
                BuildSitemap($filename,$header,$footer,$body,".xml",$k);
            }
        }

    }
}
Sitemap_posts();
```

I have total 1215 records in my DB, it writes the first 1000 properly in the first file, whereas when it writes the second file, it writes the whole 1215 records. Its not splitting at all.

When I view the looped query it comes as

```
SELECT `perma`, `subtime` FROM `posts` WHERE `pstatus` = '1' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0, 1000
SELECT `perma`, `subtime` FROM `posts` WHERE `pstatus` = '1' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1000, 1000
```

I dont know where am going wrong, its been whole night I have been struggling to get through, but no luck.

I need help in... It should split to 2 files, while writing the first 1000 links to the first file and rest 215 links to the second file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what happens. On the line

```
                    $body .= '<url>
```

you actually concatenate `$body` with the previous value of the variable - in this case the first 1000 rows. You should re-initialise `$body` for each new batch of 1000 you start. For instance, you can do it like:

```
            if($scount > 0){
            unset($body);  // Start with empty body!
            for($j=0;$j<count($results);$j++){
```

This way, for each 1000-batch starts with clean `$body`.

I hope this helps!

--

Additionally, if you accept another advise, you might optimise the query you use to get the number of total records:

```
        $sql = $con->Execute("SELECT `perma`, `subtime`
        FROM `posts` 
        WHERE `pstatus` = '1'
        ORDER BY `id` DESC");
        ...
        $count = $sql->RecordCount();
```

This unnecessarily runs a full fledged query, fetching lots of data, even sorting it. This will ultimately slow down your code quite a lot and your hosting provider will hate you for it. Instead you could something like:

```
    $count = $con->Execute("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM `posts` WHERE `pstatus` = '1'"); 
    $row = $count->FetchRow();
    $count = $row['count'];  // This is your record count
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html

Comment: as per your suggestion on `$row['count'];` query, it generates only single link in sitemap but where as when I echo $row['count']; it shows 1215 perfectly. I dont know whats wrong.

Comment: I didn't get your last question. please elaborate.

Comment: When I execute the query of ` $count = $con->Execute("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM `posts` WHERE `pstatus` = '1'");` and then loop with the rest of the code, it only generates single link in sitemap. But when I echo the value of `$count = $row['count'];  // This is your record count`  the count showing perfect as 1215. I dont understand why its generating a single link in sitemap file when i use your suggestion with that count query.

Comment: Hmm, did you remove the `$count = $sql->RecordCount();` right before `$page =  ceil($count/1000);` ?

Comment: That is weird. Please check what is the generated `$Query` and `$scount`.

Comment: Its done, I used `$count->fields['count'];` then it worked, thanks again for your time and support. Appreciate it.